# Launch Google earth in Power apps

Tags: java, spring-boot, azure, powerapps, google-earth

I am searching for solution:
When I click on icon in powerapps canvas app, it will call REST API, api will create kml file and Google Earth should launch with generated kml file.

Currently I am doing following steps

1. created canvas app in power apps with google earth icon.
2. on click of icon its calling REST call with request body, based on input generating KML file
3. putting kml file in /var/tmp folder.
4. if icon is bind with Launch("gearth://http://server:7474/assets/Google.kml"), its launching google earth with kml file, which I kept in resource folder for testing purpose.

Problem: I am not able to put kml file in resource folder by java program. I searched and found resource folder is read only.

Is there any way we can access file in /var/tmp folder?
Or can I do file creation/download in powerapps, upon getting response from REST call.

Comment: https://collab365.com/11th-day-xmas-adding-static-google-map-powerapp/
https://powerapps.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/image-control-static-maps-api/
https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/Can-we-open-quot-Google-Maps-Application-quot-from-PowerApp/m-p/250595#M73546